# How do I retrieve all the code from lightning?

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, vs-code

My boss had been muddling through Salesforce by creating custom objects and triggers using the Lightning Web Interface. I want to pull all his work down in VS Code, commit it to git, and continue development on it. How do I do that? Each sfdx command I run says it requires a project or a manifest.xml file. But I don't know how to create one for code that was created in Salesforce.

Answer (score 3):

For SFDX specifically, in VS Code (assuming the [Salesforce Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode) and [SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) are installed), you can just take the following steps.

First, create a new project (View > Command Palette > SFDX: Create Project With Manifest), enter the project name and the folder name to save it in.

Next, authenticate, if necessary, with (View > Command Palette > SFDX: Authorize an Org), and follow the prompts.

After this, if necessary, set the default user name from the terminal via (Terminal > New Terminal) and entering the command `sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=username-or-alias`.

Once you have all that configured, continue to use the terminal to retrieve the metadata:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -x package.xml
```

You'll find all your source in force-app/main/default.

---

You can customize all this via package.xml and sfdx-project.json to change the metadata to retrieve and/or path settings.

Comment: Should be sfdx force:source:retrieve -x manifest/package.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using workbench? Under the "Migration" tab select "Retrieve" and you can pull down metadata based on an xml package.

https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataRetrieve.php

Then you build out your package.xml file and use that to determine what types of metadata you want to retrieve. Some examples are here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm